# iText - How to get PDF Binary for Printing

Tags: java, android, pdf, printing, itext

I want to send pdf bytes to the printer in my Android project. I watched tcp packages of an application that did this before. Does exactly that:

1-) Sending paper size, page size, margins with PLC commands.

2-) It then sends the PDF bytes. (I marked it for you)

[image]

Sends bytes like this

```
.*b20W....................
```

This is an example of how bytes are sent. (20 Bytes after W)

If I try to send a pdf created with Adobe, the bytes look like this:

[image]

This is not working for me. Because it sends a byte array that is different from the above and contains many unnecessary things.

My question is exactly this: How do I get pdf bytes like above? Will iText help me with this?

This is my pdf file (I used the same file for both tcp-packages):

[image]

NOTE: My printer is HP Deskjet 2630

EDIT: I am sending the adobe pdf file to the printer as follows

```
    fun connect() {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try{
            val soc = Socket("192.168.1.22", 9100)
            val dout = DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream())
            dout.writeUTF("1")
            val buffer = ByteArray(8192) // or 4096, or more
            while (file.inputStream().read(buffer).also({ count = it }) > 0) {
                    dout.write(buffer, 0, count)
            }
            dout.flush()
            dout.close()
            soc.close()
        }
        catch (e:Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

The file here is the pdf file created with adobe. When I send its bytes to the printer, it sends a lot of unnecessary information. I wonder how do I send the same pdf via iText without unnecessary information. Because that way the printer doesn't understand bytes.

EDIT2: I have created a new iText Pdf.

```
        val pdf = PdfDocument(PdfWriter(file.path))
        val document = Document(pdf)
        val line = "Hello! Welcome to iTextPdf"
        document.add(Paragraph(line))
        document.close()
```

Now I'm trying to split it into bytes. But again, it contains a lot of unnecessary information.

[image]

Comment: Can you share both PDF files? The one created by your Android application and the other created by Adobe. Also, the code used, in a way that is reproducible for other people.

Comment: Actually, I don't need to send a sample file. Because my only problem is how can I get bytes from itext pdf as above. It doesn't matter how the pdf file is.

Comment: Check my edit please. Thanks

Comment: did you try `byte[] pdf = Files.readAllBytes(pdfPath);`